# Git checkout files dont sync

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

I made a git init in my project folder on my computer that I then pushed to my github repo.

But when I do a **git checkout -b bla_bla** edit some files, then do a **git checkout master** to get back to master, my files will still be changed from when I was in "bla_bla"

How can I checkout and do some changes and checkout back to master without having the changes in my master aswell?

Comment: You'll have to commit the changes for them to "stay" in a branch.

Comment: Or, stash your changes.

Comment: Oh.. commit. Thanks /a git n00b

Answer (score 0):

If you committed (or want to trash) your changes to your bla_bla branch, you can checkout master and then do
`git reset --hard HEAD` and `git clean` to get a clean working dir.